# Visual Studio 2012 Style Window

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, styles

I'm interested in creating a window in WPF that has a style similar to the way Visual Studio 2012 looks (the seamless window with color around edges, color is not necessary). This might not be a very programming - oriented question, but does anyone know of a library like the Fluent Ribbon library that can create this style?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you look for the term "Custom Window Chrome" you'll get answers about what you're looking for.  I wrote a library a while back that did a lot of the work for this:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell

There's also a blog post linked there that explains how it's implemented:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wpfsdk/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf

Comment: Is this compatible with windows 8?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for. This seems to be more of an aero chrome type of thing.

Comment: It should be compatible with Windows 8, though I don't know for sure how the DWM calls will respond.  The library lets you draw your own chrome.  You can integrate with Aero glass, but you're free to draw whatever you want over the caption and resize areas.  VS 2010 was implemented using these techniques (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/23/wpf-in-visual-studio-part-5-window-management.aspx); I expect the 2012 version didn't rewrite too much of that logic.